# Find the row that optimises different criteria in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following numpy array matrix:

```
example = np.array([[1.5525672727035909, 0.9550488599348534, 0.04495114006514658, -4757.845003575899, -4747.172432255857, 1], 
                    [1.3050643768242065, 0.962214983713355, 0.03778501628664495, -5024.418466943938, -5013.745895623896, 2], 
                    [1.3950687447554788, 0.9596091205211726, 0.040390879478827364, -4922.047207088476, -4911.374635768434, 3], 
                    [1.2375603195101852, 0.9641693811074918, 0.035830618892508145, -5105.942048800849, -5095.269477480807, 4], 
                    [1.2375603195101852, 0.9641693811074918, 0.035830618892508145, -5105.942048800849, -5095.269477480807, 5], 
                    [1.2375597985998075, 0.9641693811074918, 0.035830618892508145, -5105.942048800849, -5095.269477480807, 6], 
                    [1.2375597985998072, 0.9641693811074918, 0.035830618892508145, -5105.942048800849, -5095.269477480807, 7], 
                    [1.215059487982556, 0.9648208469055375, 0.03517915309446254, -5134.107976656531, -5123.435405336489, 8], 
                    [1.1250535573201497, 0.9674267100977199, 0.03257328990228013, -5252.243174800487, -5241.570603480445, 9], 
                    [1.1250551200512835, 0.9674267100977199, 0.03257328990228013, -5252.243174800487, -5241.570603480445, 10]])
```

As you can see it consists in an array of different parameters in 10 different rows, (the last column is an index of the rows). What I am trying to do is get the row index of the one that meets better different criteria from different columns.

For instance, the closer to zero from column 1, the closer to 100 from column 2, the further from zero from column 3 and 4. In a way, I would like an optimisation that gets the index of the row that meets different criteria the best.

So far I have only got the select the rows for the columns based on the individual criteria, but I have not get to the point where it takes all the considerations together.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your question is not specific enough. To select the best column you need to decide on some kind of "cost". What's more important being very close to zero for column 1 or very close to 100 for column 2? Is it better to be spot on for column 1 and meh for column 2 or to be decent in both.

Figuring out this cost function is the most important thing. once you decide on your cost function you can compute it for every column and then decide which is best!

Comment: Hi @SimonTartakovksy, I think the ideal would be to have a collection of different rows that match all the criteria, in fact, the best option is assuming the conditions are equivalent in utility. In my data I have thousands of rows like this so anything that reduces it to a subset of rows would be a hit. However, If I had to choose to only to options, the cost function would be taking the max of col 1 first, and then the min of col 4, for instance. In fact, not very important, I would like to see how would someone apply a cost function defined like this to an array data in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment you need to be more specific about your cost function.

In general a quadratic error function is a good idea for reasons I won't go into here. In that case it's simply a case of doing the following:

```
goal = np.array([0,100, 0 ,0,0,0])
weight = np.array([1, 1, -1 , -1,0,0])

costs = np.sum(((example - goal)**2)*weight, axis = 1)

print(example[np.argmin(costs),-1])
```

`goal` defines the points that are the targets.
`weight` represents if we want to be close to them or far from them.

So to compute the cost you substract the goal from the example and you are left with distances. Next you square them (this gets rid of negative signs, alternatively you can take the absolute value) and multiply them by the weights. Finally you need to sum up the individual column costs to get the overall row cost to select the "cheapest" one. You can then pick out the row index (the last column)